# Pass props to React-Native-Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

I'm using the [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal). Is it possible to pass props like an image address to the modal? I checked but could not find any documentation.

Comment: Can you clarify upon what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I want to show images in a ListView and onPress of any Image want to open the Image in a modal. How do I pass the path of the Image to the Modal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass it a child component for it to render. So, you would need to build out a component like normal, but then pass it to the Modal component for it to render. From their [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal#a-complete-example):

```
render() {
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}>
        <Text>Show Modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Hello!</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}>
            <Text>Hide me!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

So, you would want to wrap `<Image src={your_url} />` along with whatever else you'd like the modal to display with Modal tags. Alternately, you could pass the whole component to Modal via its children prop:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Modal children={<YourCustomComponent {...props} />} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your Modal with a custom component and have the modal render an image which is passed as a prop. Set visibility to true when the corresponding image is pressed and the modal will pop-up with that image.